# Getting this error while using Neovis.js with Neo4j. - neovis_js_dist_neovis_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4___default.a.default is not a constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, neo4j, vis.js

I am trying to use `Neovis` library to visualize `Neo4j` graph data in webpage.

**In Component.ts**

```js
import NeoVis from 'neovis.js/dist/neovis.js';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.draw();
  }

  draw() {
    const config = {
      container_id: 'viz',
      server_url: 'bolt://localhost',
      server_user: 'neo4j',
      server_password: 'test'
    };

    const viz = new NeoVis.default(config);
    viz.render();
  }
```

```html
 <div id="viz"></div>
```

But I am getting this error on app load
`ERROR TypeError: neovis_js_dist_neovis_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4___default.a.default is not a constructor`

Comment: `const viz = new NeoVis(config);`

Comment: @ritaj No error now but graph dispaying only nodes .. no relationships

Comment: After updating the cypher query to return relationship. Its working fine. Tysm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `default` did the trick. After adding cypher query graph is working

```js
draw() {

    const config = {
      container_id: 'viz',
      server_url: 'bolt://localhost',
      server_user: 'neo4j',
      server_password: 'test',
      initial_cypher: 'Match (n)-[r]->(m) return n,r,m'
    };

    const viz = new NeoVis(config);
    console.log(viz);
    viz.render();
  }
```